# SQL subquery error, returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to write a query but I don't know why I am getting an error that says:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
SELECT CAST(Title AS CHAR(30)) AS 'Title'
     , CAST(Content AS CHAR(70)) AS 'Content'
     , PostedDate AS 'Date'
     , CAST( ISNULL(
        (SELECT Upvote
        FROM Ratings
        WHERE Ratings.FK_PostID = Posts.PostID)
        , 0) AS CHAR(10) ) AS 'Upvotes' 
FROM Posts
;
```

Comment: The error seems quite clear.  What part do you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you want to *count* or *sum* the values.  If so:

```
SELECT p.Title, p.Content, p.PostedDate AS Date,
       (SELECT SUM(r.Upvote)
        FROM Ratings r
        WHERE r.FK_PostID = p.PostID
       ) as Upvotes
FROM Posts p;
```

Notes:

- `SUM(r.upvote)` may not be the correct logic.  Perhaps you want `COUNT(*)` or something similar.
- I see no reason to cast the columns to strings.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to get the number of votes per post? Why not just use a join:

```
SELECT p.Title,  p.Content, p.PostedDate AS 'Date', COUNT(r.Upvote) AS 'Upvotes'
                         FROM Posts p
                         LEFT JOIN Ratings r ON r.FK_PostID = p.PostID
                         GROUP BY p.PostID, p.Title ORDER BY p.PostID ASC
```